# How to use ffmpeg vstack to have both audio tracks?

Tags: ffmpeg, vstack

I have simplest ever question, which I can't find an answer here. How to `vstack` and get sound from both videos?

I use simply:

```
ffmpeg -i e:\tt140_H.mp4 -i e:\tt140_m.mp4 -vsync 2 -filter_complex vstack e:\tt140+.mp4
```

but get only first track, not both.

**EDIT**

When I try

```
ffmpeg -i e:\tt140_H.mp4 -i e:\tt140_m.mp4 -vsync 2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack,amerge[a]" -c:a aac e:\tt140+.mp4
```

I get error:  `Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_vstack_0' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_amerge_1' filter input pad 0 (audio)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `amerge` or `amix` depending on your requirements.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-amerge-1

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-amix

Here's an `amix` example:

```
ffmpeg -i 'Brassic01.mp4' -i 'Brassic03.mp4' -vsync vfr -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack=2::shortest=0[out0];[0:a][1:a]amix[a]" -map [out0] -map [a] -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but I have 2 questions: 1) Why there's double colon `::` there? And why I got 80mb from files of 10mb and 16mb by default? Because of ultrafast preset? Normally I get the same sizes. Of course, I can set `-b:v 2000k`.

Comment: @Peter.k The double colon is just an error on my part, I was adapting a previous command and the `-preset` is just a habit. I value speed over size, feel free to drop the `-preset` entirely. https://write.corbpie.com/ffmpeg-preset-comparison-x264-2019-encode-speed-and-file-size/